# How to strip non-digit characters from an id attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am reading the id from a list tag an add it to a `pre` tag like this:

```
$('pre').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
});
```

for example, the list tag has this id:

```
<li id="Comment_123">
```

For the pre tag, I want to remove the first 8 characters from the id; so 
the pre tag should become this id:

```
<pre id="123">
```

How can I achieve this with the code I already have?

Comment: You want to remove the first 8 characters, or you want to strip everything except digits...?

Comment: that also OK, there should be only numbers left for the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip everything except digits, you could use `.replace(/\D/g, '')`:

```
$('pre').each(function () {
  this.id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

- `\D` - Matches [any non-digit character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters).
- `g` is a [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) to match all occurrences.

In other words, all occurrences of any non-digit character(s) are replaced with an empty string, `''`.

Answer (score 3):

If you know all the ID's have the same structure, you can remove what comes before the _ (inclusive).

```
var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id').split('_').pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's set at the first 8 chars, then use `substring`

```
var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
var shortened = id.substring(8, id.length);

$(this).attr('id', shortened);
```